# opencv 2.3 copyTo function not working as it was in 2.2

Tags: c++, opencv

So, I am writing some OpenCV C++ code and I am having trouble porting my code from OpenCV 2.2 to 2.3.1. The main problem right now is the `Mat::copyTo` function. In the documentation or the release notes, they have mentioned that while the new version of this function takes OutputArray, the old code should still work (i.e., `Mat::copyTo(Mat &m)`). The thing is that it does not work.

Here's my code

```
void copyMatRows(Mat &src,Mat &dest,int start_pos)
{
    for(int i=0; i < src.rows;i++)
    {
        int dest_y = start_pos;

        if(start_pos < 1)
        {
            dest_y = dest_y+i;
        }
        src.row(i).copyTo(dest.row(dest_y));

    }
}
```

So in the above code the line

```
src.row(i).copyTo(dest.row(dest_y));
```

fails with the error

> no matching function for call to cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::Mat) candidates
>   are: void cv::Mat::copyTo(const cv::_OutputArray&) const

Any help would be appreciated? any way in which i can fix this?

What I am trying to do is to get N number of matrices and combine them all in one big matrix.

Comment: There are more efficient ways to copy matrices in OpenCV.  Have a look at using ROIs.

Comment: well that would make sense, but how? the functions adjustROI and locateROI work somewhat differently to the cvSetImageROI....i believe ROI relates to growing the image matrix , before doing an operation

Comment: They work slightly differently, but accomplish exactly the same result in the end.  The equivalent to cvSetImageROI is the Mat constructor that takes in a Rect.  Have a look here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your function, but I'm not sure it's doing exactly what you want:

```
void copyMatRows(Mat &src, Mat &dest, int start_pos)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++)
    {
        int dest_y = start_pos;

        if(start_pos < 1)
        {
            dest_y = dest_y + i;
        }

        Mat destRow = dest.row(dest_y);
        src.row(i).copyTo(destRow);
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**
This should do pretty much what you're looking for:

```
void appendMatRows(Mat &src, Mat &dst, int start_pos)
{
    for(int i = start_pos; i < src.rows; i++)
    {
        dst.push_back(src.row(i));
    }
}
```

The main caveat with the `push_back` member function is that the number of columns must be the same, but I don't think you're too worried about that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yea this above method works fine, but i want to append matrix rows