# OpenCV copyto doesn't accept argument cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following two lines of code, which creates an ROI, and then wants to copy the sub_image (Mat) to the mask (Mat):

```
Rect roi(Point(x - quick_d_2(n2), 0), Size(n2, y + quick_d_2(m2)));
sub_image.copyTo(mask(roi));
```

Which should work according to the documentation of OpenCV (since it should accept Mat as an argument), yet I get the following error during compilation:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::Mat)’
note: candidates are:
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1651:10: note: void cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::OutputArray) const
```

`

Why am I getting this error? And if it does not accept Mat as an argument (which I guess it should), how do I convert it to OutputArray? I can't seem to find a convert method in the OpenCV documentation for it.

Main question: **how do I convert Mat to OutputArray?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [opencv 2.3 copyTo function not working as it was in 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005627/opencv-2-3-copyto-function-not-working-as-it-was-in-2-2)

Comment: Thanks for the link, the answers provided there unfortunately seem rather specific to the situation/question asked there. It does however 'explain' why the documentation might be lacking behind on which arguments it swallows. Nevertheless, Mat still should work according to: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#inputarray-and-outputarray as it writes: You can assume that instead of InputArray/OutputArray you can always use Mat, std::vector<>, Matx<>, Vec<> or Scalar. When a function has an optional input or output array, and you do not have or do not want one, pass cv::noArray().

Comment: Seems to be exactly the same as your question, but maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: Well it might be me, but the solution doesn't seem 'clean'. It looks like a work around by copying each row individually, I'll give it a shot though, thanks.